# Leaflet.js & Leaflet.Draw - create polyline drawing button

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

is it possible to add an L.Control button, so when the user clicks it, the user would be able to draw a polyline? I can easily add the default L.Control.Draw button, but this is not what I want, I just want the functionality of this button :)

Comment: To clarify, do you want to be able to call the draw initializing function with your own custom buttom?

If yes, then this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775103/leaflet-draw-mapping-how-to-initiate-the-draw-function-without-toolbar?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Rather than overriding (hiding) functionality from the outside, you can use L.Control.Draw's (which I'm a big fan of) definition to show or not show what you want.  So, to use L.Control.Draw to only show a button to define a polyline, you could set it up as:

```
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
        position: 'topleft',
        draw: {
            polyline: { <whatever options you want> },
            polygon: false, 
            rectangle: false,
            circle: false,
            marker: false
        },
        edit: false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix would be to add the CSS property `display:none;`, which moves the control buttons up without messing up the UI. Here's the following classes you'd want to hide:

- leaflet-draw-draw-marker
- leaflet-draw-draw-circle
- leaflet-draw-draw-rectangle
- leaflet-draw-draw-polygon

Alternatively you could fork [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js-plugins/blob/master/plugins/leaflet-draw/v0.2.2/leaflet.draw.js#L9) and just remove the parts pertaining to other geofeatures.