# What function/event is fired by the "Cancel" button in leaflet.draw?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I set up a custom button to initiate drawing as per [How to click a button and start a new polygon without using the Leaflet.draw UI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22738698/4047679) and [How to initiate the draw function without toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775103/leaflet-draw-mapping-how-to-initiate-the-draw-function-without-toolbar). However, once someone clicks on this custom button, I can't figure out how to imitate the behaviour of the `Cancel` button so that I can have something like

```
<input type="button" onclick="stopEdits()" value="Click to Stop Drawing">

function stopEdits() {
    //Cancel Drawing
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this was resolved by the following code, `drawer.disable()` cancels the marker placement.

```
var drawer = new L.Draw.Marker(map, drawControl.options.marker);

function startDrawing() {

    drawer.enable();
}

function stopDrawing() {
    drawer.disable()
}
```

The issue I had had was that I was previously doing too much in the same line:

```
var drawer = new L.Draw.Marker(map, drawControl.options.marker).enable();
```