# Leaflet.draw delete last point

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm trying to create a set of buttons to replace the default L.Control.Draw buttons (only for a polyline, in my case). Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775103/leaflet-draw-mapping-how-to-initiate-the-draw-function-without-toolbar)

I have been able to replicate Draw, Edit, Delete and their associated 'Cancel' and 'Save' buttons. What I cannot figure out is how to replicate the 'Delete last point' function for the Draw button.

Comment: Please add code and error you have at this point and see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for asking better questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the `deleteLastVertex` method on your draw instance:

```
var drawPolyline = new L.Draw.Polyline(map, drawControl.options.polyline).enable();

drawPolyline.deleteLastVertex();
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!