# How to use out side leaflet.draw control with leaflet.snap?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

First of all I would like to thank you all for amazing libraries like `leaflet/leaflet.draw` and `leaflet.snap`.

What I want to do is outside `leaflet.draw` control with supporting leaflet snap. This is nicely working with in side map draw control.

Below I show how did I call outside leaflet draw control:

```
<div><button id="draw_mark1" onclick="drawMarker1()" >Draw Marker1</button></div>
<div><button id="draw_polyline1" onclick="drawPolyline1()" >Draw Polyline1</button></div>

    function drawMarker1(){
        var markerDrawer1 = new L.Draw.MarkerA(map, { icon: new myIcon_xx() });     
        markerDrawer1.enable();
    }

    function drawPolyline1(){
        var polylineDrawer1 = new L.Draw.PolylineType1(map);     
        polylineDrawer1.enable();
    }
```

note:- leaflet.snap not in the tag list. I want to tag it too.

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775103/leaflet-draw-mapping-how-to-initiate-the-draw-function-without-toolbar ?

Comment: thank you for helping me..wait..i'l read and send the feedback.. ....

Comment: i read it..but its working for me..how ever i did it using little hack..but not good for production site...  in each html button click event ,i  call my custom L.DrawToolbar.include with custom  drawcontrol..

Comment: new L.Draw.Polyline(map, drawControl.options.polyline).enable(); can't call without defining drawcontrol.. &   is this drawControl.options.polyline just for options?